# Comma needed or not?

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, compound-sentences

I was reading an article and found the below sentence:

> I met Ruhail through Facebook last year but I hadn’t saved his number as I didn’t want my parents to know.

I believe the author missed commas at two places- one before **but** and second before **as**.

**I met Ruhail through Facebook last year :** This is an independent clause followed by this sentence, **"I hadn’t saved his number as I didn’t want my parents to know."**, which has two independent sentences and a comma should be placed before as.

In my view the correct sentence should be this one:

> > I met Ruhail through Facebook last year, but I hadn’t saved his number, as I didn’t want my parents to know.

Secondly, what type of sentence is this? Can I call it a compound sentence ?

Comment: Many people would put a comma before *but*. However, it's not an absolute rule. Putting a comma before *as* depends on how you interpret that part of the sentence. It may mean something different than you think. As in *I hadn't saved his number **because** I didn't want my parents to know. [It was because I hadn't had a pen on me at the time.]* If it's acting *restrictively*, then you can't separate the last part of the sentence from it with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the commas that you suggested are **correct**, though the second comma I would consider optional. As you said, a comma should always appear before the coordinating conjunction "but" if it precedes an independent clause. Though there is no hard and fast rule about a comma preceding a phrase, it does sound better before the "as," too.

Secondly, the sentence would be considered **compound-complex**, because "as I didn't want my parents to know" is a dependent clause that includes a verb. It would be a compound sentence if it were deleted.

Hope this helps!